# JS Database word counts

Tags: javascript

I have currently a problem and I don´t know what to do. Perhaps can somebody help me.

Namely, I constructed a little database. First of all, an input window appears. In this window we can write a word (for example: "informatics"), and this will be saved in my function database and became an ID number.

But I want two important things more: when 2 objects have the same name (example: "informatics") then put them together and count them.
When someone enters "football" 13 times, then I have a numerator, then show me that.

I hope your understand what I mean.

Here is my code, I'm very grateful for support.

```js
function Database () {
  this.database = [];
}
  Database.prototype = {
   insert: function (obj) {
    this.database.push(obj);
  },
  where: function (prop, val) {
    if (!prop) {
     // Es wird keine Property übergeben. gib in diesem Fall
     // den Inhalt der gesamten Datenbank zurück.
      return this.database;
    }
    for (var resArr = [], i = 0; i < this.database.length; i++) {
      if (this.database[i][prop] === val) {
        resArr.push(this.database[i]);
       }
     }
     return resArr;
  },
  update: function (whereProp, whereVal, updateProp, updateVal) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.database.length; i++) {
       if (this.database[i][whereProp] === whereVal) {
         // Objekt gefunden!
          this.database[i][updateProp] = updateVal;
        }
      }
  },
  delete: function (prop, val) {
    if (!prop) {
      // Lösche alles
      var currentDatabase = this.database;
      this.database = [];
      return currentDatabase;
     }
     for (var i = 0; i < this.database.length; i++) {
        if (this.database[i][prop] === val) {
           // Objekt gefunden!
           return this.database.splice(i, 1);
        }
       }
     }
}
```

```js
function Database () {
  this.database = [];
  var index = 0;
  this insert = function (obj) {
  obj["id"] = this.index++;
  this.database.push(obj);
 };
}
```

```js
function where () {
    var eingabe = prompt("Nach was suchst du? Gib ein oder zwei Schlüsselbegriffe ein.", "Wort1, Wort2");
   if (eingabe != false) {
     alert("Danke für deinen Eintrag! Er wurde in die Datenbank eingespeichert!");
     db.insert({"apliki": eingabe});
  }

  else {
    alert("Etwas stimmte nicht mit deiner Eingabe...");
    prompt("Bitte gib ein oder zwei Schlüsselbegrifffe ein und achte auf`s Format", "Wort1, Wort2");

  }
}
```

Comment: *"I hope your understand what I mean"* is not a technical problem statement or question. Try to narrow this down to smaller more specific issues as it directly relates to your code. Also the objective is still too vague. Provide sample of expected results. Statements like *"put them together and count them"* can be interpreted several different ways. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble following your existing code. But if you just want to count things, give this a try:

```
var counts = {};
function getCount(word) {
    return counts[word] || 0;
}
function insert(word) {
    counts[word] = getCount(word) + 1;
}

insert('hello');
insert('goodbye');
insert('hello');

console.log(getCount('hello'));   // output: 2
console.log(getCount('goodbye')); // output: 1
console.log(getCount('new'));     // output: 0
```

Comment: ok, thats a good start, but my problem still exists. I think a screenshot, can better explain my problem...

Comment: db.where();

[Object 
    hallo: "welt"
     id: 0
__proto__:Object 

Object
     hallo: "welt"
    id: 1
__proto__: Object

Here that`s the problem. The same words haven`t the same ID and here is no count numerator.

Later, I will insert a String with much words and the function readout all words and show me, how ofter which word was called. :) 

Thank`s for help :)